# PendingIntent doesn't hold the data assigned to Intent when setting up notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a helper method that sets up and returns a notification that user's credentials are expired and he needs to log back in. Upon pressing this notification, I expect that he gets a login activity without being able to go back to the home screen.

I was trying to use all the flags to force the stack to be cleared (to erase history of activities), but I can still press back on the login activity and go back to the home screen (like I was never logged out). So I tried to set some extra info for the login activity to recognize if back button can be pressed or not. Nothing works: history is available and none of the extra info that I pass is recognized. Can anybody help me understand where my problem is?

Here is the helper method (in the *UiUtils* class):

```java
public static Notification getInvalidTokenNotification(Context context)
{
    SharePrefHelper.setRememberMe(false);
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    loginIntent.putExtra("CAN_GO_BACK", false);
    loginIntent.putExtra("TEST_VALUE", 12);
    // Action on click:
    PendingIntent loginPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            loginIntent,
            0
    );
    return new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_token_invalid_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notification_token_invalid_content))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_wenow)
            .setContentIntent(loginPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
}
```

Here is the code to show notification:

```java
@OnClick(R.id.debug_notification_test)
public void onClickTestNotificationBtn()
{
    // Show notification:
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        mNotificationManager.notify(UiUtils.NOTIFICATION_ID_INVALID_TOKEN, UiUtils.getInvalidTokenNotification(getApplicationContext()));
    }
    // Logout user:
    SharePrefHelper.delUser();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as the last parameter of this call:

PendingIntent loginPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            loginIntent,
            0
    );

This will ensure that you replace the extras every time you create the `Notification`